# encabezados personalizados en PhantomJS selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Necesito establecer mediante headers, el navegador que uso. Debido a que utilizo PhantomJS, el sitio web al que deseo ir dice que no es compatible, por eso ahora quiero hacer pasar el phantonJS como un chrome o firefox.

Se que es posible, pero no encuentro en internet la respuesta que me ayude en concreto.

Uso PhantomJS 2.1.1.0 en windows 7.

Comment: Puedes intentar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666067/selenium-phantomjs-custom-headers-in-python/35666152

Comment: No lo utilice porque en esta linea "driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args)" por tener windoes se coloca el url y ese codigo supongo que es para linux.

Comment: Diego supongo que te refieres a que en esa línea se coloca el path al driver, si es eso no tienes ningún problema, puedes pasar ambos parámetros: `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="tu_ruta_a_phantomJS", service_args = service_args)`, no creo que exista diferencia en Windows aunque nunca lo he usado en este OS.

Comment: No me ha funcionado, inclusive le tomaba un capture y se veia el sitio indicandome que el error estaba en que el navegador no era compatible, ahora solo sale en negro y no realiza la accion que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Este es el codigo que me ha funcionado:

```
desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()
desired_capabilities['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) ' \
                                                                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
                                                                  'Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("C:/Users/DIEGO/Documents/diego/scraping/phantomjs.exe",desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
```

Espero le sea de ayuda.